# Use Key Value pair for the UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, key-value

I have created a application which will list the names . Whenever the name is tapped , I want to return the age of the particular name. I am adding the names and age dynamically. If I use Key-Value pair, it will be easier to retrieve the value I guess. Can anyone tell me how to use the KeyValue(NSDictionary) pair here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *nameAgePair=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
[nameAgePair setValue:@"30" forKey:@"Name1"];
[nameAgePair setValue:@"25" forKey:@"Name2"];

NSArray *arr=[nameAgePair allKeys];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];

     UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
     [lbl setText:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

}
```

You can access the selected values like this.

```
[nameAgePair objectForKey:@"selected row"];
```

Note: If you use key-value coding your keys(names) should be unique.